# preg_match problem with allowing all keyboard symbols, but prohibit other symbols

Tags: php, preg-match

```
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\!\"\№\;\%\:\?\*\(\)\<\>\/\#\$\^\&\@\-\+\_\=\|\,\.\~\{\}\[\]\'\\\\]+$/", $sometext))
{//only symbols from keyboard entered
}
else
{//bad symbols entered
}
```

I tested this function a lot and looks like it works fine. But, I've found it works for this string as well:

```
how are you?'<>"\|/à
```

It shouldn't work because symbol `à` is not allowed. 
Please don't tell me about `stripslashes`, I know that. Also I've found if I want to allow `\` symbol, I have to write not `\\`, but `\\\\`. So did I.
Thank you.

Comment: I have found a small mistake, some backslashes were cut. The last sentence was: Also I've found if I want to allow \ symbol, I have to write not \ \ (two backslashes without spaces), but \ \ \ \ (four backslashes without spaces). So did I. Thank you.

Comment: I just tested your regex and test string, and it returned an empty array, meaning no match. Are you sure you tested correctly?

Comment: Also, the whole `\\\\` vs `\\` rant you have here is wrong; if you don't use `addslashes`, you don't need to write four backslashes; two is enough.

Comment: I get this:PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \U, or \u at
offset 17 in preg_match7.php on line 3

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \U, or \u at offse
t 17 in preg_match7.php on line 3

Comment: When you want to match a backslash, you appear to need 4 of them to match one when the pattern is in double quotes. In single quotes, I believe you only need 2.

Comment: Sorry, but `à` is present on my keyboard. As well as `ç` and some other.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work, though I can't seem to get the No character into the pattern (it's got a \? instead):

```
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s!\"\?;%:?*()<>\/#$\^&@\-+_=|,.~{}\[\]'\\\\]+$/", $sometext))
```